# After HTTP POST request UIView change delays

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have use this code to make HTTP POST request:

```
let myURL = NSURL(string: serverURL)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!)

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(responseString)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

}

task.resume()
```

I have experience that the view's `backgroundColor` changes after several seconds from the print of the responseString.

Why is that and how can I make it simultaniously?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always perform `UI` changes on main thread, so change your view's `backgrondColor` on the main thread like this way.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :)

Comment: Your api call is run on background thread so if you want to update UI with api Always update UI on main thread hope you get that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform UI changes on the main thread in order to make it faster, Because i think http requests are made asynchronously for example downloading an image. So in your code you can do as follows

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: Not just to make it faster.  It's a correctness issue.  The UI classes aren't guaranteed to work without crashing if you muck with things on a non-main thread....  :-)